# What is SNR in this case?

Tags: snr

I try to measure the SNR for a light input from a system. I will use a photodetector/photodiode which is a current source(linearly proportional to the to optical signal).

With 50 Ohm termination, I will observe the voltage signal and noise on a scope. Normally SNR in dB would be 20*log10(V_signal/V_noise).

But in this case, will the SNR be 10*log10(V_signal/V_noise)?
(I'm confused because here is optical power is linearly proportional to the current)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will still be \$20\log_{10}\frac{\text{V}_{\text{signal}}}{\text{V}_{\text{noise}}}\$, because you're describing the SNR at the output of your diode, not the SNR on the medium.